# What does "off" mean in "he'd probably better off"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions

> Based on this breakdown, it’s pretty clear that professional CRO should not be at the top of this guy’s priority list. (In fact he’d probably better off brainstorming strategies to increase his cLTV, not his conversions.)

What does "off" mean here?

Does it mean that brainstorming should not be used?

Comment: **[better off](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/better-off)** "1 in a better situation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the phrase you want to understand is not the single word "off" by itself, but "better off". There's a missing "be" before it, which probably confused you; a more readable version would be:

> Based on this breakdown, it’s pretty clear that "professional CRO" should not be at the top of this guy’s priority list. (In fact he’d probably be better off brainstorming strategies to increase his cLTV, not his conversions.)

In other words, brainstorming those strategies would benefit him more than what he is doing.